# Change UIView Position in TableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UIView in my tableview custom cell, when it appears i want to change the position of the the UIView based on certain condition.

i put this code in method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(11, 306, 302, 95);
        [cell.myView setFrame:newFrame];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
```

I'm certain that the view already have the new position based on `NSLog`.
But it still in the same position in my screen.
Is there any steps that I missed?

Comment: after this reload table

Comment: If you are using the frame with autolayout. then it will not work.

Comment: You have to set constraint of view.

Comment: and you are not reloading the table after update correct?

Solved my problem doing something like:
   `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell.myView setFrame:newFrame];
    });` try it might solve yours as well..

Comment: 0yeoj, it works...thanks a lot. Perhaps you can submit it as answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The frame you are assigning based on certain condition, needs to be assigned inside LayoutSubviews method of UITableViewCell Class.